# Joomla front end not displaying

Tags: php, joomla, frontend

I am quite new to joomla. 
I installed joomla 3.0 trough c-panel and the backend seems to work fine. Default templates are displaying. The problem occur when I try to switch to another template, namely: Ja_Lens for 3.x. I only installed the basic template, but it does not seem to work. All I get is a white page. Have tried to delta everything, even uninstalled joomla and the installed it again, but the same thing keeps happening. The template was downloaded and the zip archive containing the default template installed trough extension manager by browsing to said zip file.

there are no index.html files and /index.php does not work.

Please advice...

Comment: Do you also get this problem with the default Protostar template that is shipped with Joomla 3.x?

Comment: No, the protostar template works

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because of the new template you have installed.

There is something wrong in that template's source files(may be syntactically or semantically).

You have to check all php files of that plugin if you are able to do this, if not then you have to hire a Joomla developer.